# UnlockAndRelock method in WOPI host

Tags: c#, ms-wopi

I have been working on the implementation of the WOPI client and in which scenario we have to use UnlockAndRelock method.

> The UnlockAndRelock operation releases a lock on a file, and then
>   immediately takes a new lock on the file.

When we need this to be invoked during a file open- checkout- edit file- check-in operation?
Do we need to release a lock and relock when the file is already locked by me for edit?

ref : [UnlockRelock](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/UnlockAndRelock.html)